# Existe alguma maneira de substituir um número por outro em um DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataset, big-data

Tenho um dataset para analisar, e ele em alguma colunas contém valores que referenciam outros. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de substituir um valor numérico por outro.

Tentei fazer essa tarefa com o `replace` mas não deu certo.

Deixo uma imagem com o código, e [o link para o dataset que estou analisando](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Drug+consumption+%28quantified%29).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código por escrito no corpo da pergunta e aperte `Ctrl` + `k` com o código selecionado

Comment: Ao perguntar ou responder não publique código como imagem, código deve ser colocado como texto: Referência [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas: Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema! Peço desculpa por ter colocado a questão assim desta forma, não voltará a acontecer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O replace tem que ser feito com um dicionário.

```
df['variavel'].replace({old_value : new_value})
```

Exemplo replicável:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
#trocando 1 por 214
df['A'] = df['A'].replace({1:214})
df
     A  B  C
0    0  5  a
1  214  6  b
2    2  7  c
3    3  8  d
4    4  9  e
```

Comment: Irei experimentar como me indicou, obrigado!

Comment: Ok. Veja a documentação para mais detalhes e alternativas nesse método: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Mesmo assim não funciona, dá-me o mesmo erro.

Comment: O comando é esse mesmo. Vou editar minha resposta para incluir um exemplo replicável